# Force all files under the specific path to download (not open in browser) using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I know how to force all jpg files to download using .htaccess, like below:

```
AddType application/octet-stream jpg
```

But now I want to force all files (no matter what format) under the specific path to download using .htaccess

For example:

Force all files under the path `/home/user/public_html/files/attachments` to download and not open in browser directly.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `RewriteRule` to reach your goal, no need to use `AddType`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/home/user/public_html/files/attachments/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ".+\..+" "-" [T=application/octet-stream,L]
```

This will force any kinds of formats to download in the browser only when the path matches `/home/user/public_html/files/attachments`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the possible extensions which are in the folder to AddType. like,

```
AddType application/octet-stream .jpg .doc .mov .avi .pdf .xls .mp4
```

I came across similar situation and couln't able to find a better way of doing it so posting this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Force a `Content-Disposition` header.

```
Header always set Content-Disposition "attachment"
```